# react-select default value is not rendered when using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to set the `defaultValue` for on the `<Select />` component from react-select package.

However, when I do set the default value, using a react hook (useState), it does not render the default values.

If I was to hard code the array, it renders he default values fine.

**What I have so far**

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-2e3unk?file=/example.tsx:0-608

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function AnimatedMulti() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      { value: 1, label: "Label 1" },
      { value: 2, label: "Label 2" },
      { value: 3, label: "Label 3" }
    ];

    setValues(data);
    setDefaultValues([data[0], data[1]]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      defaultValue={defaultValues}
      isMulti
      options={values}
    />
  );
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expectation**

I am expecting the select component to render **two** default values, however nothing has been rendered.

**Question**

How can I load the default values using react hook `useState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value prop to set the selected options, and then keep updating the values from the state.
Here is the sample code for the same.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function AnimatedMulti() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      { value: 1, label: "Label 1" },
      { value: 2, label: "Label 2" },
      { value: 3, label: "Label 3" }
    ];

    setValues(data);
    setSelectedValues([data[0]]);
  }, []);

  const onOptionChange = (options) => {
    // Selected options...
    console.log("options...", options);
    setSelectedValues(options);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      value={selectedValues}
      isMulti
      options={values}
      onChange={onOptionChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Very nice and simple alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set default value after component have rendered.

> Uncontrolled components are components that manage their own state/value. They should not have a value prop (or in other words, value == undefined). If you need to set a value on those, you use the defaultValue prop. But this prop only works on mount / first render of the component. You usually access their state by using a ref, listening to the onChange handler or during form submission (using FormData).

Ref: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4942#issuecomment-987649622

You can try using values attribute to set default values.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function AnimatedMulti() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = [
      { value: 1, label: "Label 1" },
      { value: 2, label: "Label 2" },
      { value: 3, label: "Label 3" }
    ];

    setValues(data);
    setDefaultValues([data[0], data[1]]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      value={defaultValues}
      isMulti
      options={values}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however now the values cannot be removed.